# Selenium in Python: Select the second element with given link text

Tags: python, xpath, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to click all of the links on a web page that contain the link text "View all hits in this text." Here's what some of the html on the web page looks like:

```
<a href="/searchCom.do?offset=24981670&entry=4&entries=112&area=Poetry&forward=textsCom&queryId=../session/1380145118_2069"><b>View all hits in this text</b>
<br>
</a>

[...]

<a href="/searchCom.do?offset=25280103&entry=5&entries=112&area=Poetry&forward=textsCom&queryId=../session/1380145118_2069"><b>View all hits in this text</b>
<br>
</a>
```

If there were only one such link on the page, I know I could click it using something like:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('View all hits in this text').click()
```

Unfortunately, this method only ever identifies and clicks the first link on the web page with the link text "View all hits in this text." I therefore wanted to ask: is there a method I can use to click the second (or nth) link with link text "View all hits in this text" on this page? I have a feeling I may need to use xpath, but I haven't quite figured out how I should go about implementing xpath in my script. I would be grateful for any advice others can lend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is `find_elements_by_link_text()` ([docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html)):

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('View all hits in this text')
for link in links:
    link.click()
```

Also, you can use xpath to get all links with a specified text:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[text() = 'View all hits in this text']")
for link in links:
   link.click()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks so much, @alecxe. I'm using the `find_elements_by_link_text()` method, and I'm receiving an error flag: `TypeError: argument of type 'WebElement' is not iterable.` Do you happen to know if there is a workaround for this error? I'm most grateful for your assistance.

Comment: @dduhaime that's strange `find_elements_by_link_text()` (note `s`) should return a list of `WebElements` and it should be iterable. Are you sure you are using the code snippet I've provided as is?

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you. I received that error because I attempted to perform illegitimate operations on one of the links list objects. All is well now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

Try this below code:

```
driver.find_elements_by_link_text('linktext')[1].click()
```